# how to insert multiple rows into a table with 10g

Tags: insert, oracle10g, rows

how do I insert into a table that has first_name and last_name columns several rows with data "john smith", "mike fechke"? I tried to run this but it did not work

insert into test(first, last) values
('john','smith'),
('mike','fechke')

Answer (score 1):

Use **INSERT ALL** statement to insert multiple rows in a single SQL:

For example,

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (first, last) VALUES ('john','smith')
  INTO mytable (FIRST, LAST) VALUES ('mike','fechke')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

**NOTE** You must **COMMIT** after the above insert.

Comment: but why it does not save the rows? after restarting sql the table becomes empty with no rows on it

Comment: Did you COMMIT the changes? After insert, do `COMMIT;`